# How to create a grid of photos where you can hover them and they will change into other photos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to create a grid of photos where you can hover over them and they will change into other images. I've tried placing the image on CSS as background image but when you hover, the other picture doesn't seem to be exactly the same size (when it actually is).

I also tried using two images method (one on top of the other) and it works well with only one image on the page but with a grid of images, it doesn't work because of the `position: absolute`.

The only way that I found that "sort of" works is by replacing one image for the other but then you don't have a smooth transition (fade into another image).

[Here is the access to code pen (seems to work better)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpJwgL):

Code:

css:

```css
.pages-content {
  max-width: 400px
}

.left {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.right {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.bottom {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

img.a {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

img.a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
img.b {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <section class="container pages-content">
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 bottom">
        <img src="https://d1mwzmktacfw26.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/23105511/Frontier-400x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>        
        <!-- trying to use hover to change images
     <img src="https://d1mwzmktacfw26.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/23105511/Frontier-400x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid a"/>
        <img src="http://www.tikbok.com/rahalat/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/1-400x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid b"/> -->
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 right">
  <img src="http://cheb-room.ru/uploads/cheb/2016/11/w9RC4W-QqXw-200x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 bottom left">
  <img src="http://cheb-room.ru/uploads/cheb/2016/11/w9RC4W-QqXw-200x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
   </div>
    </div>

 <!-- Second block -->
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 right ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 push-md-6 col-sm-12 bottom left">
            <img src="http://www.animated-gifs.eu/category_cartoons/avatars-100x100-cartoons-spongebob/0038.gif" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 pull-md-6 col-sm-12 bottom right">
            <img src="http://www.animated-gifs.eu/category_cartoons/avatars-100x100-cartoons-spongebob/0038.gif" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 bottom">
            <img src="http://donsmaps.com/clickphotos/dolnivi200x100.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 bottom">
            <img src="http://markcarson.com/images/SunBird-7-200x200.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
  </div>
   </div><!--./col-md-6-->
   <div class="col-md-6 bottom col-sm-12 left project-image">
  <img src="http://www.bravacasa.rs/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Odlaganje-stvari-za-decu-slika-7-505x1025.jpg" width="200" class="img-fluid"/>
   </div>
  </div><!--./block 2-->
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: in the codepen and the code snippet is something supposed to happen when you hover over the images? right now they're just static images. i know you're trying to have it so that one fades into the other...

Comment: @Anthony The actual code he has been using for the animation has been commented out in the html.

Comment: I posted an answer below. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have been playing around with your problem for a bit. I came up with this solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rpwewg. It appears to be working the way you want it. I ran into two issues figuring it out.

The first one was that you are using the position: absolute on the images. it will place the image relative to the closest parent that is relatively positioned. Since in your example the parent div was a bootstrap class I decided to create a new div with position: relative assigned to it and gave it a class of images-wrapper.

Now I just needed to overlap the images over each other, just as you did in the example. But...If I make both images position: absolute the browser won't have an height assigned to the images-wrapper class. Therefore I decided to give one of the images a relative position and the other one absolute so it would overlap.

hope it helps :).

**html**

```
<body>
  <section class="container pages-content">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 bottom">
              <!--img src="https://d1mwzmktacfw26.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/23105511/Frontier-400x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"/-->        
              <!-- trying to use hover to change images-->
                            <div class="images-wrapper"><img src="https://d1mwzmktacfw26.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/23105511/Frontier-400x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid a"/>
              <img src="http://www.tikbok.com/rahalat/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/1-400x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid b"/> <!---->
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
              <div class="images-wrapper"><img src="https://d1mwzmktacfw26.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/23105511/Frontier-400x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid a"/>
              <img src="http://www.tikbok.com/rahalat/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/1-400x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid b"/>
                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 bottom left">
                            <img src="http://cheb-room.ru/uploads/cheb/2016/11/w9RC4W-QqXw-200x200.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Second block -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 right ">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 push-md-6 col-sm-12 bottom left">
                  <img src="http://www.animated-gifs.eu/category_cartoons/avatars-100x100-cartoons-spongebob/0038.gif" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 pull-md-6 col-sm-12 bottom right">
                  <img src="http://www.animated-gifs.eu/category_cartoons/avatars-100x100-cartoons-spongebob/0038.gif" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 bottom">
                  <img src="http://donsmaps.com/clickphotos/dolnivi200x100.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 bottom">
                  <img src="http://markcarson.com/images/SunBird-7-200x200.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--./col-md-6-->
                        <div class="col-md-6 bottom col-sm-12 left project-image">
                            <img src="http://www.bravacasa.rs/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Odlaganje-stvari-za-decu-slika-7-505x1025.jpg" width="200" class="img-fluid"/>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--./block 2-->
</body>
```

**css**

```
.pages-content {
  max-width: 400px
}

.left {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.right {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.bottom {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

img.a {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

img.a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
img.b {
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    }
.images-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.hover-img {
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-1 {
  background-image: url(https://d1mwzmktacfw26.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/23105511/Frontier-400x200.jpg);
  width: 400px;
  /*
  height: 200px;*/
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.img-1:hover {
  background-image: url(http://www.tikbok.com/rahalat/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/1-400x200.jpg);
}

.img-2 {
  background-image: url(http://cheb-room.ru/uploads/cheb/2016/11/w9RC4W-QqXw-200x200.jpg);
  /* width: 200px;
  height: 200px;*/
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.img-2:hover {
  background-image: url(http://www.animated-gifs.eu/category_cartoons/avatars-100x100-cartoons-spongebob/0038.gif);
}

.img-3 {
  background-image: url(http://donsmaps.com/clickphotos/dolnivi200x100.jpg);
  /*width: 200px;
  height: 200px;*/
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.img-3:hover {
  background-image: url(http://markcarson.com/images/SunBird-7-200x200.png);
}

.img-4 {
  /*max-width:400px;*/
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <section class="container pages-content">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="flex-item hover-img img-1"></div>
      <div class="flex-item  hover-img img-2"></div>
      <div class="flex-item  hover-img img-3"></div>
      <img src="http://www.bravacasa.rs/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Odlaganje-stvari-za-decu-slika-7-505x1025.jpg" class="flex-item  img-4" />

    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to set the images as background and hover background, then set `background-size:cover` to keep the image display "uniform" in size. No need for Javascript code at all.

**Here, [I forked your Codepen for a demo](http://codepen.io/flamedenise/pen/OpJorx)**. I only applied the `hover` effect to the first image for you to check out. Let me know if it helps.

For the "smooth transition", CSS also takes care of it for you. Feel free to change the div width (and height) to serve your needs better:

```
div.row div {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

div.row .col-md-12:first-child {
  background-image: url('https://d1mwzmktacfw26.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/23105511/Frontier-400x200.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.row .col-md-12:first-child:hover {
  background-image: url('http://donsmaps.com/clickphotos/dolnivi200x100.jpg');
}
```